# Apache adds a trailing slash to something not a subdirectory

Tags: apache-2.4

In the directory `foo`, I have the file `bar.html`, and no other subdirectories or files. I also have `Options +MultiViews` in my `.htaccess`. None of my other rules are redirects or do any rewriting.

When I try to access `https://example.com/foo/bar`, I expect it to access the file `bar.html`. Instead, it redirects to `https://example.com/foo/bar/`, and then rightly 404s, because there is no subdirectory `bar`.

This didn't used to happen. It started happening after I accidentally made a `bar` subdirectory under `foo`. I tried to access it, realized the mistake, and then deleted it; this is when it started happening.

What can I do to diagnose this problem, if not fix it?

Comment: Restart Apache.

Answer (score -1):

Restarting Apache, clearing my cache, and then accessing the site fixed it.